# How can I use encrypted xml file as application resources for xaml data binding?

Tags: wpf, xml, encryption, resources, xmldataprovider

I want to use encrypted xml file as application resource for easy xaml data binding. Xml file are encrypted in different application. I can use unencrypted xml for data binding. I cant use the same method for encrypted xml because the file is encrypted when it is loaded. I have to decrypt it first before it can be use. Problem is, where do I put decryption algorithm?

Here how i create the encrypted files(code for decrypt and verifying decrypted data are omitted)

```
            RijndaelManaged algorithm = null;

            algorithm = new RijndaelManaged();
            string passwordBytes = "password"; //password here
            byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("salt"); // salt here (another string)
            var p = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes);
            algorithm.IV = p.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize / 8);
            algorithm.Key = p.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize / 8);

            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load("Bands.xml");

            // Encrypt the "Bands" element.
            Encrypt(xmlDoc, "Bands", algorithm);
            xmlDoc.Save("encryptedBands.xml");
```

To decrypt, i just call these(assuming xmlDoc and algorithm are same as above.

```
Decrypt(xmlDoc, algorithm);
```

Here are encrypt and decrypt algorithm based on msdn(nothing special).

```
        public static void Encrypt(XmlDocument Doc, string ElementName, SymmetricAlgorithm Key)
    {
        // Check the arguments.   
        if (Doc == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Doc");
        if (ElementName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ElementToEncrypt");
        if (Key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Alg");

        var elementToEncrypt = Doc.GetElementsByTagName(ElementName)[0] as XmlElement;
        // Throw an XmlException if the element was not found. 
        if (elementToEncrypt == null)
        {
            throw new XmlException("The specified element was not found");

        }

        var eXml = new EncryptedXml();

        byte[] encryptedElement = eXml.EncryptData(elementToEncrypt, Key, false);

        var edElement = new EncryptedData();
        edElement.Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl;

        string encryptionMethod = null;

        if (Key is TripleDES)
        {
            encryptionMethod = EncryptedXml.XmlEncTripleDESUrl;
        }
        else if (Key is DES)
        {
            encryptionMethod = EncryptedXml.XmlEncDESUrl;
        }
        if (Key is Rijndael)
        {
            switch (Key.KeySize)
            {
                case 128:
                    encryptionMethod = EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES128Url;
                    break;
                case 192:
                    encryptionMethod = EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES192Url;
                    break;
                case 256:
                    encryptionMethod = EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES256Url;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Throw an exception if the transform is not in the previous categories 
            throw new CryptographicException("The specified algorithm is not supported for XML Encryption.");
        }

        edElement.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(encryptionMethod);

        // Add the encrypted element data to the  
        // EncryptedData object.
        edElement.CipherData.CipherValue = encryptedElement;
        EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(elementToEncrypt, edElement, false);
    }

    public static void Decrypt(XmlDocument Doc, SymmetricAlgorithm Alg)
    {
        // Check the arguments.   
        if (Doc == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Doc");
        if (Alg == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Alg");

        // Find the EncryptedData element in the XmlDocument.
        var encryptedElement = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("EncryptedData")[0] as XmlElement;

        // If the EncryptedData element was not found, throw an exception. 
        if (encryptedElement == null)
        {
            throw new XmlException("The EncryptedData element was not found.");
        }


        // Create an EncryptedData object and populate it.
        var edElement = new EncryptedData();
        edElement.LoadXml(encryptedElement);

        // Create a new EncryptedXml object.
        var exml = new EncryptedXml();


        // Decrypt the element using the symmetric key. 
        byte[] rgbOutput = exml.DecryptData(edElement, Alg);

        // Replace the encryptedData element with the plaintext XML element.
        exml.ReplaceData(encryptedElement, rgbOutput);

    }
```

I want to use the encrypted xml data as data source for easy data binding in xaml. I declare xml data at application level for application wide access. Here's how I declared it in App.xaml.

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="encryptedBandsDataSource" Source="/RemoteConfigurator;component/encryptedBands.xml" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Problem is, I need to decrypt the xml file before App.xaml is even loaded. Is it possible to do that. How do I do that. Where do I decrypt the xml file?

In short, how can I use encrypted xml file as application resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options, a quick one and a clean one...

**Option 1 (quick): Decrypt file before loading the app**

If you decrypt your file, before base.OnStartup(e) is called in app.xaml.cs, it should work...

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace MainApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            DecryptXml();
            base.OnStartup(e);

            MainBootstrapper bootstrapper = new MainBootstrapper();
            bootstrapper.Run();
        }
    }
```

}

**Option 2 (clean): Custom XmlDataProvider to handle encrypted XML files**

Another option is to write a custom XmlDataProvider, say `EncryptedXmlDataProvider`, which holds an `EncryptedSource` property and some other properties to specify how to decrypt the file. `EncryptedXmlDataProvider` can decrypt the file, when `EncryptedSource` property is set. This way, the Data is blendable and you have a reusable type. A bit more work but much cleaner than the solution proposed above.

Comment: So this is where you load method before app.xaml is called. Thank you sir. Anyway, any chance for blend to be able to read and digest the file?

Comment: Wow. I never thought it was possible. Thank you sir.